# Adwhirl Receives but Doesn't Show Admob Ad

Tags: android, admob, adwhirl

I'm having the hardest time getting adwhirl to work with admob in my application.

adwhirl.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/llAd">
    <com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/timer_ads"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

my activity

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.adwhirl);     
    AdWhirlManager.setConfigExpireTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);   
    AdWhirlTargeting.setAge(23);
    AdWhirlTargeting.setGender(AdWhirlTargeting.Gender.MALE);
    AdWhirlTargeting.setKeywords("online games gaming");
    AdWhirlTargeting.setPostalCode("94123");
    AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(false);

    AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = (AdWhirlLayout)findViewById(R.id.timer_ads);      

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new

      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int diWidth = 320;

    int diHeight = 52;

    int density = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;    

    adWhirlLayout.setAdWhirlInterface(this);

    adWhirlLayout.setMaxWidth((int)(diWidth * density));

    adWhirlLayout.setMaxHeight((int)(diHeight * density));

    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);


    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llAd);       

    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

   // layout.addView(adWhirlLayout, layoutParams);

    //layout.addView(textView, layoutParams);

    layout.invalidate();
     //new ScanThread().execute(Util.getAuth(this),Util.getURL(this));
}
```

android manifest

```
<meta-data android:value="(my-adhwhirl-key)"

    android:name="ADWHIRL_KEY"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdMobActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
```

log

```
    09-12 02:04:10.403: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(729): Creating adWhirlManager...
09-12 02:04:10.403: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729): Locale is: en_US
09-12 02:04:10.413: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729): Hashed device ID is: 7d1dd13a2fa91c0ad174cb69a11549a3
09-12 02:04:10.413: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(729): Finished creating adWhirlManager
09-12 02:04:10.423: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729): Prefs{55aa3dea659c46c0bef87c711a5d524e}: {"config": "{"extra":{"location_on":1,"background_color_rgb":{"red":255,"green":255,"blue":255,"alpha":1},"text_color_rgb":{"red":0,"green":0,"blue":0,"alpha":1},"cycle_time":15,"transition":8},"rations":[{"nid":"6b5563f8f4a64cd5b7abfbbeec54e0f8","type":1,"nname":"admob","weight":100,"priority":1,"key":"a14e6d5816c612a"}]}
09-12 02:04:10.423: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729): ", "timestamp": 1315792993877}
09-12 02:04:10.423: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(729): Using stored config data
09-12 02:04:10.423: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729): Received jsonString: {"extra":{"location_on":1,"background_color_rgb":{"red":255,"green":255,"blue":255,"alpha":1},"text_color_rgb":{"red":0,"green":0,"blue":0,"alpha":1},"cycle_time":15,"transition":8},"rations":[{"nid":"6b5563f8f4a64cd5b7abfbbeec54e0f8","type":1,"nname":"admob","weight":100,"priority":1,"key":"a14e6d5816c612a"}]}
09-12 02:04:10.493: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(729): Rotating Ad
09-12 02:04:10.493: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729): Dart is <27.61096846453517> of <100.0>
09-12 02:04:10.573: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729): Showing ad:
09-12 02:04:10.573: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729):     nid: 6b5563f8f4a64cd5b7abfbbeec54e0f8
09-12 02:04:10.573: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729):     name: admob
09-12 02:04:10.573: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729):     type: 1
09-12 02:04:10.573: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729):     key: a14e6d5816c612a
09-12 02:04:10.573: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729):     key2: 
09-12 02:04:10.583: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(729): Valid adapter, calling handle()
09-12 02:04:10.643: WARN/InputManagerService(60): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4075f600 (uid=10018 pid=525)
09-12 02:04:11.094: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Displayed com.trandroid/.AddTorrent: +790ms
09-12 02:04:11.283: DEBUG/dalvikvm(60): GC_CONCURRENT freed 710K, 45% free 4267K/7751K, external 1252K/1764K, paused 9ms+7ms
09-12 02:04:58.393: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
09-12 02:09:58.403: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
09-12 02:14:58.413: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
09-12 02:19:58.423: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
09-12 02:24:58.433: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
09-12 02:29:58.443: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

I've set up my admob publisher id on adwhirl. Please help!